# Sencha touch 2.0 : adding the 'empty' selection to a selectfield

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I understand that a 'selectfield' is meant to choose among the existing 'options' that you provide (or from the entries in a 'store').

What I would like to have, is to possibility for the user NOT to select any of the options.
On top of that, it would be nice to have the ability to display a placeholder when no option is selected (something like "Select one...").

The current selectfield behaviour is that if you provide no initial value or one that doesn't belong to the 'options' (or your 'store'), then the first item is selected by default.

About the picker, I don't mind if there is no way to go back to the empty selection after one option has been chosen. What I want is the possibility to leave the selectfield with an empty selection if you don't touch it.

Has anyone a valid solution for doing this (overriding selectfield? extending a new field ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both overriding `Ext.field.Select` and extending new field are able to achieve what you need but I really prefer the second solution. In my experience, no matter user selects "empty" or "non-empty" options from your selectfield, subsequent processes are always taken. For example:

- Save it to the database as "empty" value.
- Simply ignore it.

Moreover, as it's actually an option, user can choose "empty" option again after choosing "non-empty" option at anytime.

Of course it will annoy a little bit, especially when you're working with a lot of Stores. But in consideration with flexibility and ease, I recommend this solution.

Comment: Thanks, with the second solution, you mean adding an entry to every store I have ? Is there a way to add such an entry to all stores automatically. Since my stores are loaded from local storage, can I add this 'fake' entry after loading with the proxy?

Comment: you can add automatically by listening to `load` event

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic implementation of Thiem Nguyen's solution to extend the Select field. Hope it will save some time ;)

```
/**
 * Adds an additional option to a select field filled by a store
 * @cfg {mixed} valueFieldValue Value of the added option
 * @cfg {string} displayFieldValue Text to display for the added option
 */
Ext.define('util.field.SelectPlus', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Select',
    xtype: 'selectfieldplus',
    alternateClassName: 'Ext.field.SelectPlus',
    requires: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        displayFieldValue: '',
        valueFieldValue: ''
    },

    /**@override
     * Insert our item each time the store is loaded
     * @param {Ext.data.Store} store The refreshed store
     */
    onStoreDataChanged: function(store) {
        if(store.findExact(this.getValueField(), this.getValueFieldValue()) === -1) { //prevent infinite loop ;)
            var item = Ext.create(store.getModel());
            item.set(this.getValueField(), this.getValueFieldValue());
            item.set(this.getDisplayField(), this.getDisplayFieldValue());
            store.insert(0, item);
        }
        this.callParent([store]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic solution... :-)

Comment: This solution does not work if you are using placeHolder property in the view.. and I don´t know why..